# Desktop entry not working for SQL Manager

Tags: 17.04, sqldeveloper

I have Ubuntu 17.04. I have a desktop entry that allows me to start SQL Developer. This desktop entry used to work, but now it have stopped working... This is my entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=SQL Developer
Icon=/usr/lib/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Exec=/usr/lib/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
```

To edit it I use:

> sudo -i gedit /usr/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop

When i run i terminal:

> /usr/lib/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh

SQL developer starts. What can be the error here?

**ls -l command output:**

```
sindre@s-elitebook:~$ ls -l /usr/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 146 sep.   4 08:44 /usr/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop
sindre@s-elitebook:~$
```

Comment: Run `ls -l /path/to/file.desktop` and add to your question

Comment: Added ls -l command

Comment: Probably there is a difference in environment variables. What does the `/usr/lib/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh` script look like?